# jQuery functions, one to display dropdown on click and another to get selected item from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an unordered list (HTML below and Javascript code is below).

The first function "display_dropdown_multiple" works for me.  However, I'm having issues with the 
second function "get_selected_owner".

After making a selection from dropdown menu.  I want the second function to return the 'selected value'.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function display_dropdown_multiple(event) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
      $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').text($(this).text());
      $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
       });
});

function get_selected_owner() {
    return $('#owner').find('option:selected').val();
    });        
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" id="owner" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Owner <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="owner-dropdown-menu">
      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">major</li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" id="owner"><input type="hidden" onclick='display_dropdown_multiple(event)' id="ownerId" name="ownerId" value="Owner 1" >Owner 1</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">minor</li>
      <li><a href="#" id="owner"><input type="hidden" onclick='display_dropdown_multiple(event)' id="ownerId" name="ownerId" value="Owner 2" >Owner 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="owner"><input type="hidden" onclick='display_dropdown_multiple(event)' id="ownerId" name="ownerId" value="Owner 3" >Owner 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. IDs have to be unique
2. There is no `<option>` which you're targeting.

### Solution

Construct a `<select>` with options you intend to use with unique ids and then you're code will work fine.